# draw polygon from user entered vertices google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have on my web application a text area that allows the user to enter the vertices of a polygon. i want to implement a button that when clicked, a polygon with entered vertices will be drawn in a google maps.
the vertices will always be in the following format:

```
25.82024674666931, 55.66104912743973,
25.54465656761206, 48.11048789757425,
25.22561664287819, 5.57756899014949,
25.47485219998054, 26.21461743851616
```

what is the best way to do it.

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Suggest you take a look at the [Polygon section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) and the [Polygon API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only a few steps, without complications if you trust the input to always be clean.

First, convert the comma-separated text to an array of LatLngs.

```
  function textToLatLngs(text) {
    var dots = text.value.split(",");
    var latLngs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i += 2) {
      latLngs[i/2] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(dots[i]),
                       parseFloat(dots[i+1]));
    }
    return latLngs;
  }
```

Next, with the LatLngs you can define a polygon:

```
  function drawPolygon(vertices) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: "#f33",
      fillColor: "#fce",
      paths: vertices,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

Finally, link the HTML and Javascript with an event listener (I put mine in `initialize()`)

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.0, 25.0),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(
      document.getElementById("button1"), 
      'click',
      function() {
        drawPolygon(textToLatLngs(document.getElementById('coordsinput')));
      });
  }
```

With an HTML form like:

```
      <form id="form">
        <input id="button1" type="button" value="get polygon">
        <br /><br />
        <textarea id="coordsinput" cols="22" rows="20">
        25.82024674666931, 55.66104912743973,
        25.54465656761206, 48.11048789757425,
        25.22561664287819, 5.57756899014949,
        25.47485219998054, 26.21461743851616
    </textarea>
      </form>
```

The button will draw new polygons each time the button is clicked. If you want to just move a single polygon, you need to call setPaths when the button is clicked.

http://jsbin.com/enepis/edit#preview